# C# AssemblyFileVersion usage within a program

Tags: c#, assemblyinfo

I'm working on a program, and I'm trying to display the assembly *FILE* version

```
    public static string Version
    {
        get
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(asm.Location);
            return String.Format("{0}.{1}", fvi.FileMajorPart, fvi.FileMinorPart);
        }
    }
```

At the moment, this only returns the first two version numbers in the "AssemblyVersion", not "AssemblyFileVersion." I'd really like to just reference the AssemblyFileVersion rather than store an internal variable called "Version" that I have to update both this and the assembly version...

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("3.5.0")]
```

That's my AssemblyFileVersion from AssemblyInfo.cs. I'd like to just reference the "3.5.x" part, not the "1.0.*" :/

Thanks,
Zack

Comment: You're already 99% of the way there, just change the return to fvi.FileVersion

Comment: see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528418/492 to get the version info from a specific DLL, rather than the parent executing app.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use ProductMajorPart/ProductMinorPart instead of FileMajorPart/FileMinorPart :

```
    public static string Version
    {
        get
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(asm.Location);
            return String.Format("{0}.{1}", fvi.ProductMajorPart, fvi.ProductMinorPart);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Err. I just realized it's getting the .dll's version! Not exactly what I am wanting. I want the executable version. (Forgot to mention that it's being called from a .dll)

Comment: Assembly asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

Comment: Note that fvi.FileVersion will give you the formatted string directly (all four parts), if that's what you need...

Answer (score 6):

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

FileVersionInfo fv = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

Console.WriteLine("AssemblyVersion : {0}", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString());

Console.WriteLine ("AssemblyFileVersion : {0}" , fv.FileVersion.ToString ());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    var fileVersion = GetCustomAttributeValue<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>(assembly, "Version");

    private static string GetCustomAttributeValue<T>(Assembly assembly, string propertyName)
        where T : Attribute
    {
        if (assembly == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)) return string.Empty;

        object[] attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);            
        if (attributes.Length == 0) return string.Empty;

        var attribute = attributes[0] as T;
        if (attribute == null) return string.Empty;

        var propertyInfo = attribute.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (propertyInfo == null) return string.Empty;

        var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(attribute, null);
        return value.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the version of the currently executing assembly you can use:

```
using System.Reflection;
Version version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

The Assembly class can also load files and access all the assemblies loaded in a process.

Comment: it is AssemblyVersion, not AssemblyFileVersion

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will have to use FileVersionInfo class.

`System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(FullpathToAssembly)`

Comment: The example I showed uses FileVersionInfo. But it only returns the "AssemblyVersion" attribute.

Comment: Oops. That is stupid of me not to see the question completely. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     _log.InfoFormat("*************{0} **** Version: {1}************  ", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version);
  }
```

Output

> INFO Global - *************CustomerFile **** Version: 1.0.17.2510************