# Get dll file-version using javascript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can we get the file's version number using javascript or JQuery in HTML page?

Comment: Where does this file/DLL live? On the server or on the client?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, this requires communication with the server though,

1. Send the path of the .dll you would like read the version from to the server
2. Get the version number from the .dll fike ([Programmatically get the version number of a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755504/programatically-get-the-version-number-of-a-dll))
3. Send the file version back to the client

I'm not sure if this would be the best approach, but it does the trick.

You could also do something like this:

1. Read the content of the file as binary string (client, ReadAsBinaryString FileReader API)
2. Send the binary string to the server
3. Read the binary string in memory and get the file version from there
4. Send the file version back to the client

I don't have experience with the second approach.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I am not allowed to get is using any programming language as it is simple HTML page.