# Require at least version x.x.x.x of a DLL

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is there a way to have the .NET compiler enforce (by producing a compile error) that a .NET project requires **AT LEAST** version x.x.x.x of a particular DLL to compile successfully and run?

Comment: It has necessarily to be a compiler error? Checking it at the start of the application (and throwing an error or showing a warning or something like that) would be quite easy and the result would be basically the same. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755504/programatically-get-the-version-number-of-a-dll.

Comment: Long answer:no.  [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You can write a pre-build command to compare versions.