# ASP.NET - Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("~/bin/MyFile.dll").FileVersion
```

When I make this call, I get the following error:

"Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized"

Is there any way to get the version of a DLL in an ASP web app?  Code behind is VB... but I'm guessing it doesn't matter if it's VB or C#.

It must work in RELEASE, and when the app is deployed to a production environment.  I've searched the interwebs but only found a lot of DEBUG vs. RELEASE config.

I've also tried this with no help:

http://torulflundgren.blogspot.com.au/2010/03/cannot-obtain-value-of-local-or.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the title of your question have to do with the question itself?

Comment: what is fqFileName  ?

Comment: Fixed.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically get the version number of a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755504/programmatically-get-the-version-number-of-a-dll)

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. The link posted by tonythewest mentions nothing about the error I am receiving. I also tried using AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"c:\path\to\file.dll").Version and I receive the exact same exception:

"Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away."

Answer (score 0):

> FileVersionInfo representing the version information associated with
>   the specified file.

I try this on my custom dll, this work correctly

```
    FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"C:\HBK.SystemCore.dll"); 

    string version = fvi.FileVersion;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `assembly`?  You create it but never us it.

Comment: if get current assembly use assembly.locator

Comment: Not useful.  You basically posted the EXACT same code that is giving me an error.

Comment: I updated answer. what's wrong ?  Can you send an error please

Comment: The error is listed in the initial post, as well as the post title:

"Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized"