# Programmatically get the version number of dotnet core library dll

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, assembly-name

How to get the version number programmatically from any .NET Core library DLL?
For e.g: "api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll"

The same question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755504/programmatically-get-the-version-number-of-a-dll) but it is not working for core libraries listed below:

- api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
- api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll

sample code

```
string file = @"C:\dotnet_core_lib\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll";
string  version = System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(file).Version.ToString();
```

I am getting following error message:
**Error Message**: "Could not load file or assembly 'api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest."

Comment: The files starting with api-ms-* are not dotnet assemblies. Here is a way to check if the dll is assembly or not. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/assemblies-gac/how-to-determine-if-a-file-is-an-assembly