# Determining an easy yet thorough manner of verifying if a ASP.NET Web Forms was deployed properly on a standalone Microsoft IIS Server?

Tags: dll, deployment, webforms, versioning, binaryfiles

Here is information about our development environment:

- .NET Framework 4
- Visual Studio 2010
- ASP.NET Web Forms

When we want to deploy to Production or UAT environments, we have to pass on Published files to our IT Operations/Infrastructure team.
To elaborate, we hand over (via SVN subversion repository ):

\Binaries\bin\  directory that contains dlls, some xml files, etc.

Also, we hand over (via SVN subversion repository ):

\src\ directory that contains aspx files, ascx files, gifs, jpegs, etc. (i.e., mainly front-end UI files)

Also, we hand over SQL Script files that need to run in the Production Database DB. (via SVN subversion repository ):

\SQLScripts....

We've been having problems with updating the website.  We deployed the aforementioned files, but the Business Testers, Business Clients, etc., do Not see the changes in Production.

It may be because of developers inadvertently/mistakenly  forgetting to commit binaries or source files to SVN.
Or IT Operations/Infrastructure team members forgetting to deploy something....blah blah....list goes on....

Now if SQL Scripts whether SQL Scripts get updated or Not or Run again or Not in Production DB, it would be difficult to verify, therefore, I'll just have to manually check if SQL Scripts were updated and run on the SQL SErver .

In any case, However, at the very least, for the
-Binaries
-Src
files, I was hoping there was some way of associating version numbers with said files,
and then reflecting said version numbers on an About.aspx page within Src in order to prove that they were updated and deployed to Production environment.

Basically, I'm trying to determine a way to easily check if the appropriates files (and thus corresponding changes) were deployed to Production environment.  It would be Unreasonable for IT Operations/Infrastructure team members to check if each and every feature was deployed or bugs/defects were fixed.

How could we go about doing said changes?

Answer (score 1):

if you build already updates the version number then you could do something like this: [Programmatically get the version number of a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755504/programmatically-get-the-version-number-of-a-dll)

Otherwise it would be really simple to show the file date. You could do something like

```
DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\etc\etc\yourWebApp.dll");
DateTime modification = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\etc\etc\yourWebApp.dll");
```

and then display this in about.aspx.

With that said all of this could be solved with a reasonable CI/CD pipeline, but I'm guessing thats not an option here.