# c# how to print AssemblyFileVersion

Tags: c#

How can I print in my log the version of the program that is running?
In other words, can I access AssemblyFileVersion using Console.WriteLine?

Thanks
Tony

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like something like this would work:

```
public static string Version
{
    get
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(asm.Location);
        return String.Format("{0}.{1}", fvi.ProductMajorPart, fvi.ProductMinorPart);
    }
}
```

From [another post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699580/c-assemblyfileversion-usage-within-a-program).

Answer (score 5):

```
// Get the version of the current application.
Assembly assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
AssemblyName assemName = assem.GetName();
Version ver = assemName.Version;
Console.WriteLine("{0}, Version {1}", assemName.Name, ver.ToString());
```

More on MSDN:

[Version Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(asm.Location) doesn't work for **embedded** assemblies (e.g. using [Fody's Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) to ship a single EXE instead of the executable and all of it's dependent assemblies).  In which case, the following works as a fallback:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var fileVersionAttribute = assembly.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(ca => ca.AttributeType == typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute));
if (fileVersionAttribute != null && fileVersionAttribute.ConstructorArguments.Any())
    return fileVersionAttribute.ConstructorArguments[0].ToString().Replace("\"","");
return string.Empty;
```