# How to embed AssemblyFileVersion in resource/constant/string/other?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have been reading the `AssemblyFileVersion` using code [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699580/c-sharp-assemblyfileversion-usage-within-a-program) but can no longer use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` (or any methods in the Assembly namespace) due to security restrictions.

*(As an aside - this is the security restrictions imposed by SharePoint Online which does some interrogation of your assembly upon upload and rejects it if you use certain forbidden parts of the framework)*

So are there any other ways of getting the Assembly File Version?

I am guessing no, so are there any ways of putting the AssemblyFileVersion attribute from AssemblyInfo.cs into something like a resource file or a constant so it can be accessed at runtime without using GetExectingAssembly?

Comment: You _could_ I suppose set AssemblyInfo.cs to 'Copy to Output' and then parse it manually. Or possibly write out to a file as part of your build process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I've come up with. Fugly but meets goals (single place where AssemblyFileVersion is defined) without any MSBuild tricks to write out AssemblyFileVersion into resource file.

**File : AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("MyProject")]
...
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(MyProject.AssemblyInfo.AssemblyFileVersion)]

namespace MyProject
{
    static internal class AssemblyInfo
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The AssemblyFileVersion of this web part
        /// </summary>
        internal const string AssemblyFileVersion = "1.0.3.0";
    }
}
```